# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS GNOME 3.36.3 periodic mouse and keyboard lag

Tags: gnome, 20.04, keyboard, mouse

Just installed fresh Ubuntu on a fresh machine. I'm very happy except a periodic lag on the mouse. It seems everything else works great even during the lag. The mouse is wireless and came along with a keyboard (MS).
I have intel i5 processor and intel UHD graphics.
I checked the log and the only shady thing I see is already mentioned (but remains unsolved) here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1857392

I also made sure to update everything via Software & Update.
I'm hooked up to the front mic and aux jacks with headphones (2 to 1 aux).

Any help would be appreciated.

RZ

Edit:
@heynnema Both are Microsoft and wireless. Here the output you asked for in the order stated:

[image: myOutPut]

Edit 2:
@heynnema

```
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=9cd65f59-278f-416d-aede-189ce6ff4086 none            swap    sw              0       0
total 12
drwx------  2 reuven reuven 4096 Oct  8 03:08 .
drwx------ 23 reuven reuven 4096 Oct  8 00:45 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 reuven reuven 2476 Oct  8 03:08 application_state
-rw-rw-r--  1 reuven reuven    0 Oct  5 14:47 gnome-overrides-migrated
```

Edit 3:
@heynnema

```
>>> sudo dmicode -s bios-version
1401
>>> sudo dmicode -t 2
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: PRIME H310M-E R2.0
    Version: Rev X.0x
    Serial Number: 200265349501746
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

>>> sudo dmicode -t baseboard
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: PRIME H310M-E R2.0
    Version: Rev X.0x
    Serial Number: 200265349501746
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description:    To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x004A, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Onboard - Other
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0

Handle 0x004B, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Onboard - Video
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0

Handle 0x004C, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Onboard - Other
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 2
    Bus Address: 0000:00:14.0

Handle 0x004D, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Onboard - Other
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 3
    Bus Address: 0000:00:16.0

Handle 0x004E, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Onboard - SATA
    Type: SATA Controller
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:17.0

Handle 0x004F, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Onboard - Other
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 4
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1f.0

Handle 0x0050, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Onboard - Other
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 5
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1f.2

Handle 0x0051, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Onboard - Sound
    Type: Sound
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1f.3

Handle 0x0052, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Onboard - Other
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. What brand mouse/keyboard? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thx m8. Hope I tagged and edited correctly :)

Comment: Thanks for the info! That looks almost normal. Why such a large swap? Show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and redo `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` for me. Do you have any other USB devices connected? FYI: When adding textual info to your question, it's better to copy/paste the info, select the pasted info, then click on the {} icon to format it into human-readable.

Comment: Do you have bluetooth? Is it enabled? Do you have any bluetooth devices paired?

Comment: @heynnema Hello again :) Thanks for teaching me how to post code properly. No I actually don't have anything hooked up apart from the single usb dongle that came with the keyboard-mouse set. I dont have bluethooth, I checked in the settings menu and it confirms that, which also makes sense since I bought a simple basic desktop pc which to my understanding usually dont come with BT unless specifically asked for.

Comment: You haven't told me about the large swap partition.

Comment: @heynnema Oh right sorry. Well, I'm really new to all this and I had severe difficulties installing ubuntu properly. Especially since im trying to get a dual boot eventually with win 10. Currently I have only this Ubuntu 20.04.1 on this machine. While partitioning I had to choose a swap partition and I confess I didnt really know what that means, I was just so frustrated with the fatal grub errors in the end of the install that I just left it as is after the last successful install.

Comment: @heynnema I now see that this is an overflow space for my ram, which means that i did some stupid partitioning. Is that really bad? should I repartition via Gparted?

Comment: Swap really isn't overflow for RAM. Swap is used by the system to manage memory by swapping least recently used pages of memory in/out to swap... thereby making for more room in memory for other applications or program code. Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your swap is way excessive. Best to convert to using a 4G /swapfile. Then you can use `gparted` to add that 37G back to your Ubuntu partitions. I can show you how to do that, if you like. Show me a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you so so much for your great help! So, I did what you asked and to figure out what kind of a MB I have I found the above terminal commands. Is that it or should I open the PC case and look for something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113874/discussion-between-heynnema-and-rubenz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

ASUS PRIME H310M-E R2.0

You have BIOS revision 1401.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 1605, dated 8/11/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/PRIME-H310M-E-R2-0/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**SWAP**

Your swap is excessive at 37G. Let's change from a 37G swap partition, to a 4G /swapfile.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
```

To edit /etc/fstab, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

Comment out the following line:

```
UUID=9cd65f59-278f-416d-aede-189ce6ff4086 none   swap    sw   0   0
```

Save the edit and quit the editor.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

Save the file and quit the editor.

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Note: The 37G swap partition (/dev/sda3) is no longer used, may be deleted, and the unallocated space may be added back to your Ubuntu partition using `gparted`.