# XUbuntu 20.04 USB dongle (wireless) mouse lagging

Tags: wireless, 20.04, usb, xubuntu, mouse

I tried multiple "solutions" but nothing worked. I can't try to use USB 2.0 because the laptop only has 2 usb3.0.
tried:

[20.04 USB keyboard and mouse lag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240958/20-04-usb-keyboard-and-mouse-lag)

[laggy mouse pointer in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237310/laggy-mouse-pointer-in-ubuntu-20-04)

[How can I get rid of mouse lag under Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763413/how-can-i-get-rid-of-mouse-lag-under-ubuntu)

[Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS GNOME 3.36.3 periodic mouse and keyboard lag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280805/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-gnome-3-36-3-periodic-mouse-and-keyboard-lag)

Also, it's not the screen refresh hz since the laptops touchpad is working fine.

Comment: Do you have anything else on the USB bus, such as a large amount of storage, an external video card, or a monitor? 

Comment: nothing, only the usb dongle for the mouse, not even a keyboard

Comment: Are you using PowerTop or another power management system? If so, this could be putting the dongle into a low-power mode, which would reduce overall throughput 

Comment: no, I'm not using any kind of power management system. It's nearly brand new installed os. Only some apps for programming and the necessary packs for those few languages